# what will be the coefficient of variation?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation, interpretation, coefficient-of-variation

Suppose, Average rate of return on stock = -10%,
Standard deviation on return = 30%
What will be the coefficient of variation (CV) on this case?

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient of variation (CV) is calculated using the formula:
$$
CV = \left( \frac{\sigma}{\left| \mu \right|} \right) \times 100\%
$$

where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation and $\mu$ is the mean return.

Substituting the given values:

$$
CV = \left( \frac{0.30}{\left| -0.10 \right|} \right) \times 100\%
$$

$$
CV = \left( \frac{0.30}{0.10} \right) \times 100\%
$$

$$
CV = 3 \times 100\%= 300\%
$$

Comment: Welcome to CV, Cooper.  I don't know why this very clear post was downvoted.  I would guess those votes might be related to our site policy concerning perfunctory exercises like the one posted here -- but it's a shame the downvoters didn't offer any explanations, which is the polite (and normal, constructive) thing to do.  See [tag:self-study] and its wiki, https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info.

Comment: Thank you @whuber for the comforting, friendly message, when I noticed the downvotes it did make me feel unwelcome. But is all good now :)